# Irreducible components of the seminormalization

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme with finitely many irreducible components $V_1,\dots,V_r\subset X$. Its normalization $X^\nu\to X$ is the morphism obtained as follows: $$X^\nu=\coprod_iV_i^\nu\to X_{red}\to X.$$ Here $V_i^\nu$ is the normalization of $V_i$.  They are the irreducible components of $X^\nu$.

However, there is an intermediate scheme, the *semi-normalization* of $X$, which fits in $$X^\nu\to X^{sn}\to X.$$ There are of course factorizations $$V_i^\nu\to V_i^{sn}\to V_i.$$

> *Question*. Is it true that $V_i^{sn}$ are the irreducible components of
>   $X^{sn}$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is equivalent to this one:

> Is it true that the irreducible components of a seminormal scheme are themselves seminormal?

A curve is seminormal if it is locally analytically isomorphic to the coordinate axis in an affine space. Any subset of that has the same property (for a smaller dimensional space) so a partial answer is

> Yes, if $\dim X=1$.

However, this fails in higher dimensions, because there exist reducible seminormal schemes whose irreducible components are not seminormal. The examples are not entirely simple. See (7.9.3) and (10.12) of [the reference below](https://books.google.com/books/about/Singularities_of_the_Minimal_Model_Progr.html?id=QwgQZHvESFQC&source=kp_cover&hl=en). So the answer is

> No, in general.

On the other hand, there is an almost obvious Chinese remainder theorem type exact sequence connecting the seminormalization of the scheme, the seminormalization of its irreducible components and the semi-normalization of the pairwise intersections of the irreducible components. (I suppose one can probably continue that sequence with more intersections, so it's perhaps more like a Cech resolution type exact sequence).

A good resource for the statements I mentioned above is section 10.2 of [this book](https://books.google.com/books/about/Singularities_of_the_Minimal_Model_Progr.html?id=QwgQZHvESFQC&source=kp_cover&hl=en) by Kollár.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, it is indeed quite useful. Now I also wonder, is it however true that the $V_i^{sn}$ are irreducible, and birational to $V_i$, as in the normalization case?

Comment: Yes. See page 307 of [the same book].